# MySQL select all rows from last month until (now() - 1 month), for comparative purposes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need some help writing a MySQL query to show me rows from last month, but not the whole month, only up and until the same day, hour and minute as it is now(), but 1 month before.

So for example, if today is 5/19 at 5:25pm I need to select rows from midnight 12:00am 4/1 to 5:25pm of 4/19 (from the same year too of course).

Thanks!

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can get the first of the month, by calculating the last_day of the month before and add one day. It is awkward, but I think it is better than formatting a date as string and use that for calculation.

```
select 
  *
from
  yourtable t
where
  /* Greater or equal to the start of last month */
  t.date >= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and
  /* Smaller or equal than one month ago */
  t.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: +1 Nice way to retrieve the first day of the last month without string conversion

Comment: +1 very nice.... I used `SET @FirstDayLastMonth = (DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY));` and then `SET @LastDayLastMonth  = (LAST_Day(@FirstDayLastMonth));` for my need to get first and last day of the previous month. Thank you very much GolezTrol!!!

Answer (score 46):

Getting one month ago is easy with a single MySQL function:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

or

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Off the top of my head, I can't think of an elegant way to get the first day of last month in MySQL, but this will certainly work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,7),'-01');
```

Put them together and you get a query that solves your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE t >= CONCAT(LEFT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,7),'-01')
AND t <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 30):

Simple code please check

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be more than equal to? `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`?

Comment: How is it possible to get so many up-votes despite being the exact opposite of the right answer? Someone please clarify the sorcery behind this! (Edited the answer)

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of a MySQL date operation relevant to your question:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( now( ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH )
```

The above will return date time one month ago

So, you can use it, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE Your_Date_Column BETWEEN '2011-01-04' 
    AND DATE_ADD(NOW( ), INTERVAL -1 MONTH )
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT
     * 
FROM 
     <table_name> 
WHERE 
     <date_field> BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

Similarly, You can select records for 1 month, 2 months etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN 
    ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

See [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for info on `DATE_SUB`, `ADDDATE`, `LAST_DAY` and other useful datetime functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN
    CAST(date_format(date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01') AS date)
    AND
    date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE myDtate BETWEEN now()
    , DATE_SUB(NOW()
    , INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to avoid using `NOW()` when writing sql with your programming language, and substitute with a string.  The problem with `NOW()` as you indicate is it includes current time.  So to capture from the beginning of the query day (0 hour and minute) instead of:

```
r.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 99 DAY)
```

I did (php):

```
$current_sql_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

in the sql:

```
$sql_x = "r.date <= DATE_SUB('$current_sql_date', INTERVAL 99 DAY)"
```

With that, you will be retrieving data from midnight of the given day

Comment: You can try using something like this for current day `SELECT DAY(NOW());` and this for yesterday
`SELECT DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Answer (score -3):

maybe like this - all last month
DATE(recDate) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) )