# one month before and one day after in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to send notification emails for members when they about to expire their membership on one month before and a day after.

> Eg: If membership expire on 20/08/2014 I need to send a mail on
>   21/07/2014

I used following logic to get one month condition,

```
membership_expires<DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

But I don't know how to add one day condition on the same query.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where membership_expires = CURDATE() + interval 1 MONTH
   or membership_expires = CURDATE() - interval 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscription 
WHERE
membership_expires = CURDATE() + interval 1 MONTH - interval 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @juergen and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064820/1219200) I made up following clause

```
membership_expires>NOW() and membership_expires< DATE_SUB((DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: You really want to use `=` and not `<`, unless you want to be sending notices on more than two dates to expiring members.  (And, I should add, that your question *explicitly* states that messages are sent on only two days.)

Comment: yes you are so correct, But currently I'm using a flag to maintain the send notification records. So it wont send two times, but if I miss any due to any technical fault, on that case I think I need to use `<` instead of `=`

Comment: @JanithChinthana I find avisheks notation easier to understand than yours - and it's got the same result, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81031/2).

Comment: @JanithChinthana . . . I think you should accept Juergen's answer.  It correctly interprets and answers your question; it is concise.  The fact that you have a flag wasn't mentioned in the original question, so it is unfair to add it at this point.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I accept that answer, thanks for the valuable comments