# MYSQL Last month Query is not returning first 9 days

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying records from the last calendar month. As it is February, it should return all the records that were added on January this year.

**My Query:**

```
    `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date >= 
DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 
DAY) AND date <= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 
MONTH)), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AND campaign = '$campaign' ORDER BY date 
ASC`
```

It returns some records but skips the first 9 days. It starts showing records from 10th of the previous month. What am I missing here?

Comment: post your table along with data

Comment: Try to save the result of the date functions as fields and check their values. Or run this query in phpmyadmin (easier).

Comment: @OfirBaruch , It returns the same! Anything need to do in my phpmyadmin?

Comment: [Select Data By Date-Time From Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064687/mysql-select-all-rows-from-last-month-until-now-1-month-for-comparative-p)

Comment: @MD.AtiqurRahman show you sample data

Comment: @krishnpatel sample date "2017-01-01 07:28:49"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your date field type and make sure you have not mistaken it with varchar.

Comment: That was the culprit. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date between DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND campaign = '$campaign' ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: remove the condition ( campaign = '$campaign' ) and then check whether records are returning or not

Answer (score 0):

Try To Get Data in step by step like,

First, you should try below query.

```
SELECT Date, DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS StartDate, DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 0 DAY)  AS EndDate FROM MyTable
```

Second, If First Step give right date then get your data by directly writing your date rather than DATE_ADD function in where clause.

Third, If These will Give you write DATA then try to fetch data using DATE_ADD function.

Replay If you will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
(MONTH(date) = (MONTH(NOW()) - 1) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()))
OR
(MONTH(date) = 12 AND MONTH(NOW())=1 AND YEAR(date) = (YEAR(NOW()) - 1) AND campaign = '$campaign' ORDER BY date 
ASC`