# select rows from last month using unix

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to select all rows from a table from last month basically like this guy's asking: [MySQL select all rows from last month until (now() - 1 month), for comparative purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064687/mysql-select-all-rows-from-last-month-until-now-1-month-for-comparative-p)

But I'm using unix timespamp in the date column, so the date is like this: 1538330400

So I started to use (select rows with date equal to or earlier than today):

```
SELECT * FROM ns_trainingame t WHERE t.date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

It worked just fine.

Then, after some research I found some people using a few codes to NOT UNIX TIMESTAMPS and tried to adapt it to solve my problem.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ns_trainingame t 
WHERE t.date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
  AND t.date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))");
```

But is giving me a wrong number of rows in those conditions.

What can I do?

Comment: FYI `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` is the same as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Are you trying to get the results from last month (August) or the last month (August 30 to September 30)?

Comment: @Nick (August 30 to September 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get all results from the last month (as of posting, August 30-September 30), this is probably the easiest way. Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert your timestamp to a date and then you can compare it directly to other dates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ns_trainingame t 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(t.date) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
```